# Compare raw_input to text in a file

Tags: python

I am learning python and just trying to play with some different functions. I have created this script to match raw_input to whats in a file but it always comes back as not matching. Here is the script. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#This is a test script to check a password
word = raw_input("what is the password ")   #input data
f = open("test.txt").read()
if word == f:
    print "Match"
else:
    print "No Match"
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me `test.txt` ends with a newline.

Comment: You may want use `str.strip`: `if word.strip() == f.strip()`

Comment: One problem here could be whitespace differences.  Why don't you print the contents of `f` either way?

Comment: At least print values and see what they contain.

Comment: Is there only a single word in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be sure to remove any new line or white space at the end of the file. Otherwise, use:

```
if word == f.rstrip():
    ...
```